# Use cases for using Apache Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

As far as I understand Consumer in Kafka always polls the topic.
At least I saw it in this code:

```
ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
```

So the use cases for Kafka should be very different to a REST world. In a REST you only "poll" when you really need the data. Unnessary "polling" is just useless network traffic. If you a newspaper publisher you always want the latest news , and so you poll . Good use case for Kafka.Or maybe internet of things you want to know if a machine is about to collapse so you poll and ask the state regularly.

So I really do not understand why Kafka is used so much in microservices.
Let's say we have a microservice Order and a microservice Calculator.
If Calculator wants to calculate order of last month in a REST world he would call get /orders/month/july   for example . Which sense would Kafka make in this example ? Firstly you would not store orders in a topic rather in a table.
As far as I understand Kafka topics are like "tables". So when you use Kafka there is no other database involved. Right ?

Comment: I searched for "Apache Kafka use cases" and immediately found this on the project's website: https://kafka.apache.org/uses as well as [many other pages](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=apache+kafka+use+cases&t=fpas&ia=web) which will probably explain it better than any answer here.

Comment: thanks for the links. But still it does not answer my specific questions. I really best need an answer to my concrete question above

Comment: The problem is your whole question is based on false premises: you are comparing Kafka against API calls and databases, but _those aren't what Kafka is for_. It's like saying "Why would I want to live in a car rather than a house?" - the answer is "You wouldn't, but a car is useful for these things".

Answer (score 0):

Kafka, and messaging in general, is a good fit in microservices for a number of reasons but one is for the communication between microservices and decoupling that. It helps to alleviate the need for fault tolerance (retries in the event of network, service, etc. failures), helps with deployment models (blue/green and such), scaling, etc. You make a good point though, in others cases maybe you just want to query a database.

Of course different use cases entail different optimal architectures.  One pattern entails only have a messaging system and any request for data essentially takes the form of a request for message(s)/event(s) being (re)played so that the interested service listens for those messages and derives the data from them. This is the "Kafka are like tables" case you mention.  Which/but leads to your next question...

You can indeed, and it is a common and very useful microservices pattern, have both a database and Kafka (or other messaging system). Eg, there are a few flavors of the event sourcing pattern, but this essentially entails a microservice writing to a database and that data change being sent as an event for other services to listen to. In this way the other services receive/query their data via events as I mention, but the data is also in the database.  I can go on quite a bit on this topic and examples :) but hopefully this is in the area of something you were asking.

Full disclosure, I work at Oracle, and have written a "Simplifying Microservices with converged Oracle Database" on a lot of these topics and we'll be putting out a few more (2 specifically on messaging and Kafka as well as Oracle's Advanced Queueing/Transactional Event Queues) in the next month.  The current workshop also compares Kafka with Oracle TEQ if interested... https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/dbpm/r/livelabs/workshop-attendee-2?p210_workshop_id=637&p210_type=1

Definitely feel free to drop any further questions...